# Why is @media overridden even though my max-height is 768px and not 1280px?

Tags: html, css

My monitor resolution is 1024*768.

Depending on the resolution, I set the media in my CSS to zoom my HTML.

Finally my web background-color is red, but my max resolution height is **768px**. why is it overridden by  **(max-height: 1280px)** ?

And what I need to do if I want to zoom my web depend on the resolution?

Here is my CSS file:

```
@media (max-height: 768px) {
    html {
        zoom: 100%;
        background-color: green;   
    }
}

@media (max-height: 1280px) {  
    html {
        zoom: 125%;
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 1080px) {
    .html {
        zoom: 110%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

body {   
    height: 100%;   
    position: fixed;   
    width: 100%;   
    user-select: none;   
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
}

 ......
```

Comment: `zoom`??? Please, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: +1 transform: [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) is compatible with IE9+, zoom isn't

Comment: "zoom my (web) page" > Changing font-size, using relative units (rem FTW, otherwise em), line-height and padding, etc https://www.lullabot.com/articles/scaling-css-components-with-bem-rems-ems

Comment: as if I use scale(), some div positions changed, and my web is running in chrome, I needn't  care about IE, so i use zoom.... if I want to zoom the web to 120% and the font-size to 130%, I need to do like this？{ zoom：120%； font-size:1.08% }, 1.08=1.3/1.2(as i have zoom my web to120%), am i right?  @FelipeAls  @ Marcos Pérez Gude

Answer (score 1):

Because `max` means exactly what it says. **Anything** that fits *inside* that height will match the rule. I can go to the 12 items or less checkout at the supermarket if I have 10 items or 7 items.

All else being equal, the last rule will be applied.

Put the 768px rule at the end so it will override the ones that came before it.

Comment: seems to get it, i ever thought max-height: 1280px means : only the max height is 1280px can math the rule, seems less than this number also will math the rule, am i right?

Comment: @AdvancingEnemy — Max 1280 means "between 0 and 1280" not "between some value from some other rule and 1280"

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
@media (max-height: 768px) {
// Code Here
}
@media (min-height: 769px) and (max-height: 1080px) {
// Code Here
}
@media (min-height: 1081px){
// Code Here
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1):

`@media (max-height: Xpx)` applies to everything where the height of your display ≤ Xpx.

So if you first run `@media (max-height: 768px)` and then `@media (max-height: 1280px)`, it is the expected behavior for both to be run when the height of your display area ≤ 1280px.

I think you're going for something like this :

```
@media (max-height: 768px) {
    html {
        zoom: 100%;
        background-color: green;   
    }
}

@media (min-height: 1081px) and (max-height: 1280px) {  
    html {
        zoom: 125%;
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media (min-height: 769px) and (max-height: 1080px) {
    .html {
        zoom: 110%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

body {   
    height: 100%;   
    position: fixed;   
    width: 100%;   
    user-select: none;   
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
}

 ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media query of max-width 768px is getting overridden by 1280px